# Rendering Sprite in Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am a complete noob as far as iOS development and Swift is concerned. This is pretty basic but I don't seem to understand what is wrong with it.

Compiler is not throwing any errors. The image file is in the project (image.xcassets) and named appropriately. The UIcolor statement is working as expected. However, the code does not render sprite on the screen. Node Count is at zero. What am I Missing?

Here is the code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
        override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        let ball : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball") 
        self.addChild(ball)
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the sprite a position on screen. SpriteKit doesn't draw nodes that are not on screen.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    let ball : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball") 
    self.addChild(ball)
}
```

Try replacing with this, should position the ball in center screen.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    let ball : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball") 
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
    self.addChild(ball)
}
```

Comment: Bingo. You nailed it. Many thanks! Sorry I cannot add reputation because of my status.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need to init with size. Try something like this:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
  init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)

    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
    addChild(ball)
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your comment is valid but your code does not work as is. I get a runtime error.